# Delphi: Which exception class should be used to raise last Win32/Win64 errors?

Tags: delphi, freepascal

1. When writing a function/procedure/method that utilizes Windows API functions or functions of certain Windows DLLs (e.g. ntdll.dll), which Delphi exception class should be used to raise the last Win32/Win64 errors?

   Quoted from Delphi XE3 documentation about [System.SysUtils.EExternal](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.EExternal):

   > *"Note: `EExternal` classes represent Win32 exception codes. The `ExceptionRecord` member points to a **Win32** exception record."*

   From that point, I conclude that there are differences between Win32 and Win64 exception mechanism. What are the differences between them?

   For debugging purpose—I mean in regards to the stack frames related stuffs—, are the differences lead to different code implementation of exception handling for each platform?

Comment: As a curious aside, exceptions in Delphi don't mix well with floating point code. For example, it is possible for an external error (e.g. AV, FP math error) in one thread to result in a change to the floating point control word in a *different* thread! Go figure that one out! More details here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107411

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming that your question concerns Delphi, despite the Free Pascal tag. I'm basing that assumption on the fact that you quote the Delphi documentation.

A Windows API message should be converted into an exception by calling [`RaiseLastOSError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.RaiseLastOSError). This will raise an [`EOSError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.EOSError). That is a native Delphi exception.

The [`EExternalError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.EExternal) exception is unrelated. That's what is used when the RTL converts a system trap, e.g. access violation, maths errors etc. into a native exception. Note that Win32 is commonly used to refer to both the 32 and 64 bit Windows API. There's really only one interface with both 32 and 64 bit variants.

The underlying exception handling model is completely different between 32 and 64 bit Windows. The 32 bit model is stack based and the 64 bit model is table based. This means that the implementations of exception handling, and try/finally, are completely different between 32 and 64 bit architectures.

The original implementation in XE2 of the 64 bit table based model had a large number of faults. I am pleased to say that, following a number of QC reports submitted by myself and others, the implementation in XE3 is much improved.

Stack Overflow is not the place to go into the low-level details of the exception handling ABI of these two architectures. Instead I offer the following articles:

- [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx)
- [x64 Structured Exception Handling](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=469)

Comment: @David_Herffernan, thanks very much, the `EOSError` class is what I'm looking for. Furthermore, which exception class should be used for exceptions caused by functions of certain Windows DLLs (e.g. ntdll.dll)?

Comment: I'd say `EOSError` for all Win32 API calls. You need a Win32 error code. Most functions call `SetLastError` in case of failure. So you can call the parameterless `RaiseLastOSError` which will in turn call `GetLastError`. Some functions return a Win32 error code. In which case you capture it and call the `RaiseLastOSError` overload that takes a win32 error code as parameter.

Comment: thanks, I knew that. Actually the purpose of my further question above is to know whether there is a native exception class that can give me the dll name where the error occured.

Comment: @Astaroth Nothing like that. If you called the function, you know which DLL it is in. That's the best you can do.

Comment: The function you called might call to other DLLs. To get the function that raised the exception, call `ExceptAddr` to discover the instruction address. Pass that address to `GetModuleHandleEx` with the `Get_Module_Handle_Ex_Flag_From_Address` flag. Pass the handle to `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: @RobKennedy That would only be useful if the WinAPI function raised an  exception. Which they very seldom do. It's usually programming error, i.e. passing in a duff pointer which leads to AV, rather than a Win32 error.